# Can a struct member(function) be defined before struct itself?

Tags: c++, function, struct

I'm new to C++, and I have a question: Can a member of struct that's a function, be defined before the struct itself?

Like this:

```
void foo_t::SayHello() {
    printf("Hello,World!\n");
}

struct foo_t {
    void SayHello();
};
```

Because by using this I split `struct` in a `foo.h` and `SayHello()` function in a C file.

**EDIT::**
And then include the `.c` in the top of `.h` file. Not in end of file.

I'm sorry for don't be more specific because I new to C++ and I don't know about C++'s terms.

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to include a .c file in a header file

Comment: Is not in C files that functions body is defined and in header the prototype?

Comment: You include header files in c/cpp files. Not the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. (Point)

But you might do:

```
class foo_t;
void say_hello(const foo_t& foo) // defined in a source
struct foo_t {
    void SayHello() const { say_hello(*this); }
};
```

**But**: "And then include the .c in the top of .h file. Not in end of file." **makes me shiver**.

Comment: Is not in C files that functions body is defined and in header the prototype?

Comment: @TheMask - typically the code for a class consists of two files: a **header** that contains the class definition (and definitions of any inline member functions) and a **source** file that contains the definitions of its (non-inline) member functions. When you build an application you compile each source file separately, then **link** the resulting object files together.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can make a function proxy:

```
void foo_t_SayHello() {
    printf("Hello,World!\n");
}

struct foo_t {
    void SayHello() { foo_t_SayHello(); }
};
```

A decent compiler will inline this, resulting in no overhead.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But then I will continues to use `.c` in end of  header file...